# python, como hacer un programa que corra en el fondo sin cerrarse

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

estoy haciendo un programa que hace macros personalizadas a mi gusto, porque mi teclado no tiene tal funcion
(por ahora solo tiene ctrl+w y ctrl+t para ser mas eficiente con mi navegador)
pero al abrir el programa se abre y cierra, porque solo busco que se presione ctrl+ñ como no pasa, se cierra

¿hay alguna forma de hacer el programa "incerrable" hasta que yo vaya finalize el proceso con el taskmgr.exe?

este es mi codigo:

```
#Hola este archivo a sido creado por AFK(a file creator)

import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+ñ', lambda: keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+w, ctrl+t'))
```

PD: estoy en windows 7 professional service pack 1

Answer (score -1):

Lo más simple es que tu programa se ejecute dentro de un ciclo while. Luego hacer que se ejecute en segundo plano.

Comment: Hola fjfuente, aunque esta respuesta puede servir de guía para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Deberías editar tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué condición podrías en el `while`? ¿cómo se ejecuta un programa en segundo plano? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con eso ganarás tu primera medalla).

Comment: usar un while true, no serviria porque apenas ponga el shortcut (ctrl+ñ) se haria ctrl+w y ctrl+t infinitamente hasta que mate el programa